# Android as Socket Server, Web as Socket Client in same network

Tags: java, android, sockets, websocket

I am trying to implement a socket server on Android and Socket client on Web. I am following this link for [Android Socket Server](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/08/bi-directional-communication-between.html) .

Here is the code:

```
private class SocketServerThread extends Thread {

static final int SocketServerPORT = 6190;
int count = 0;

@Override
public void run() {
    Socket socket = null;
    DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                info.setText("I'm waiting here: "
                        + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
            }
        });

        while (true) {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(
                    socket.getInputStream());
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                    socket.getOutputStream());

            String messageFromClient = "";

            messageFromClient = dataInputStream.readUTF();

            count++;
            message += "#" + count + " from " + socket.getInetAddress()
                    + ":" + socket.getPort() + "\n"
                    + "Msg from client: " + messageFromClient + "\n";

            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    msg.setText(message);
                }
            });

            String msgReply = "Hello from Android, you are #" + count;
            dataOutputStream.writeUTF(msgReply);

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        final String errMsg = e.toString();
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                msg.setText(errMsg);
            }
        });

    } finally {
        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (dataInputStream != null) {
            try {
                dataInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (dataOutputStream != null) {
            try {
                dataOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am fetching the local IP address of the device (Usually 192.168.XX.XX). 
I have created a html file which used Web Sockets for connecting to android Socket server.

HTML Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function WebSocketTest()
    {
        if ("WebSocket" in window)
        {
            alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");

            // Let us open a web socket
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.4:6190");

            ws.onopen = function()
            {
                ws.send("Message to send");
                alert("Message is sent...");
            };

            ws.onmessage = function (evt)
            {
                var received_msg = evt.data;
                alert("Message is received...");
            };

            ws.onclose = function()
            {
                // websocket is closed.
                alert("Connection is closed...");
            };
        }

        else
        {
            // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
            alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Few things that I am doing:

- Running Server on a real Android device (No Emulator)
- Both Android Server and HTML Client are under same network.
- Android Device IP is correct.

Things that I am not sure about:
- HTML Code

I havn't used WebSockets before, so don't know if there is a problem with the HTML Client.

### EDIT

If I close the server on Android device this is the error

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.1.4:6190/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
```

Else i get Timeout error after sometime.

Comment: And what do you see on the server?

Comment: In the client server example both client and server use writeUTF/readUTF. Now what is your web client writing? Only a string or a line? A line is a string terminated with \n. Are you aware that writrUTF first writes some bytes which indicate the length of the string that will be written. And then the string itself?

Comment: I am not aware about UTF thing... I will do a search on it :)

Comment: It is much simpler to use .readLine().